# RobotFrameWork: how can I stop lines temporary from running?

Tags: robotframework, updates

RobotFrameWork:

by means of this Symbol: #  it is possible to comment lines

But I don't want to comment lines but skip temporary (for test purposes of the test) from running...

How dan I do that?

(I don't want te mix the lines that have to stay commented with the lines that are temp. comment to not run in the run).

Answer (score 2):

I would pass a flag to robot framework which can be used on lines you want to temporarily stop executing:

```
robot --variable TEMP_STOP:True smoke_tests.robot
```

Then in your code add the following snippet on lines you want to skip temporarily for that run:

```
Run Keyword If   '${TEMP_STOP}'!='True'    Log    Logs If not True
```

Also ensure there is a default value for the variable in your suite otherwise you will get and error. Thanks for mentioning this in the comments **@TodorMinakov**

```
*** Variables ***
${TEMP_STOP}    False
```

To re-enable those lines then you can just pass:

```
robot --variable TEMP_STOP:False smoke_tests.robot
```

Comment: Don't forget to have the variable `TEMP_STOP` defined in the suite with a default value, otherwise if the suite is ran without setting it in the CLI there will be an exception.

Comment: @TodorMinakov Thanks, I overlooked this step. I have updated the answer with the relevant code

Comment: we can also define all configuration variables (also flag as you said above) in an argument file. Then, on RIDE, at the 'argument' text field, you can then supply the location of the argument file such as: `-A F:\ROBOT\projects\etuis\resource\variables\version1.1\config.args`

Comment: There is a paradox in this.
In order to do what you describe you have to be at a bit of an advanced level.
However the point in time where you need this most is when you're noob.
(See my answer at the bottom of the page.). But I think you help a lot which are intermediate with RFW when they read what you did.

Answer (score 1):

In all fairness this should be solved through commenting your code by selecting the entire set of code and commenting that and reverse-commenting that same section. This will 'double comment' existing comments and when you reverse the comment on the entire block this will remain commented. In the below example I use RED, but any IDE with support for Robot Framework Script will behave similarly.

Code:

```
*** Test Cases ***
My Test Case

    Log To Console    Uncommented Start Keyword

    # Log To Console    Permanent Commented Keyword

    Log To Console    Temporary Commented Keyword

    # Log To Console    Permanent Commented Keyword

    Log To Console    Temporary Commented Keyword

    Log To Console    Uncommented End Keyword
```

[image]

Then we comment the section we want, notice the double comments:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Now we reverse the same section by selecting it and perform the toggle (un)comment:
[image]